# Gnome doesn't start after libdbus update

Tags: 10.10, gnome, dbus

Yesterday I updated dbus library via apt-get. This morning I switched on my laptop and found out that Gnome doesn't start properly (it tries to display error dialog, doesn't show any panels).

XServer works fine. Laptop is ASUS eeePC 1215n. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here are some logs:

[syslog](http://pastebin.com/vjYQv2wF)

[messages](http://pastebin.com/tV2vEUQL)

Comment: Can you post any error logs? Does gdm work (the login screen) or is it just the desktop? Can you tell is dbus is running and if not can you try and run it from the command line and report any errors?

Comment: @Martin Owens -doctormo-: I switched off login screen. I can see desktop wallpaper and Docky starts properly. But I can't run applications. I can post some logs, but how can I get them?

Comment: Do you know how to use the command line? I could get you to delete the gnome2 settings folders. But I don't know unless dbus is running.

Comment: @Martin Owens -doctormo-: Yes, I know how to use command line.

Comment: NetworkManager exits with an error, but I can't find any specific things relating to dbus. Can you delete .gnome2 from your home folder and restart?

Comment: @Martin Owens -doctormo-: Done. Nothing happened. Docky shows that Gnome periodically tries to display Gnome error dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your system is in a non-recoverable position. It might be possible to recover if an expert has access to your machine directly, but unless you have a support person you can ask for help my best advice is to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, that sucks)) Anyway, thank You! Is there any way to save my current configuration (installed applications, libraries and other stuff) ?

Comment: You can do an installation over your existing one which will save your configurations and files (basically it will keep /home and delete everything else) Just make sure to set the installer to 'not' format. Your installed apps can be saved and recovered but you need to do a google search for that if you think it's important. always keep backups of your files, VERY IMPORTANT!